# Where do I look to learn about Network Programming to Auto Configure Embedded Devices?

Tags: network-programming, embedded, network-protocols, dhcp, windows-embedded-compact

I am a 16 year Windows UI developer and am now researching Network Programming on Embedded Devices.  This is completely out of my realm of expertise.  I need to research network programming on 2 devices:

Device 1 will use Windows Embedded Compact 7 (WEC7) as its operating system.  It will need to auto-configure its network (plug and play) so that it can connect to Device 2 via Ethernet.

Device 2 will act as a switch to connect Device 1 with a PC or LAN.  Device 2 will use our custom operating system and will have 2 Ethernet ports.  We need to write our network code on that system from the ground up.

We want Device 1 and Device 2 to auto-configure themselves so the user doesn't have to do any configuration of the network.  They should just plug and play.

Device 1  <--(Plugs into)-->  Device 2  <--(Plugs into)-->  LAN or PC

So where should I look to figure out how to program this network functionality from the ground up on a our custom operating system, and where should I look to learn about Windows Embedded Compact 7 Network auto-configuration programming?  Are there any good books or online tutorials that you would recommend?

We haven't decided on the protocols we will use, that's what I'm trying to research.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is this 10/100 or 1000BaseT (gige) or faster?  do these devices already have windows drivers?  macs and phys are all their own unique beasts, some you have to download firmware to, some of those you can put an eeprom on the board with the firmware that you can program one time through the part or program before placing.  Some dont need firmware.  Some with firmware still need handholding to start up, some just turn on and work.  auto negotiations happen usually in the default mode, forcing non-auto negotiate is something you have to do more work to have happen.

Comment: so is this a programming some hardware drivers question or is this the hardware will work we need to invent or pick pick a protocol question?

Comment: We already have the hardware.  We now need to figure out the software.  Device 1 uses Windows Embedded Compact 7 so we have some good tools for that, but the other device will require us to write our own networking stuff since the OS is one we wrote ourselves.  I am looking for sources to research how to program network functionality on Embedded devices, not for hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

I found the answer, or at least a good starting point.  It's called UPnP Forum.  They have a great overview document:

[UPnP Device Architecture 1.1](http://upnp.org/specs/arch/UPnP-arch-DeviceArchitecture-v1.1.pdf)

The above document talks about getting devices to be Network Plug And Playable.  So they auto configure their IPs or use DHCP if necessary, and it talks about how this is all to be accomplished.

If anybody else knows of a good resource similar to the one above, or tutorials, please let me know.